# Pivot TSQL table with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I am passing up JSON as a parameter to a SQL stored proc.  I use a function that takes a JSON dictionary and creates a table with key value pairs (two columns) that I then use with a `COALESCE` to create dynamic sql for an `INSERT` statement.  This works fine for a single dictionary, but I need to also be able to send up JSON string that contains an array of dictionaries.  Right now, my parse function gives me this table variable:

[image]

What I need is a table variable like this:

[image]

I can get the column names from the first table with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT element name from @JSONTable
```

I should mention that these elementname's can and will change.  I will not know the number of distinct elementname values.

UPDATE - Using Umair's answer, I am getting close:

```
DECLARE @JSONString AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @JSONString = '[{"ravid":3,"ravversion":2,"taskid":3},{"ravid":4,"ravversion":7,"taskid":99}]'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JSONTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #JSONTable


CREATE TABLE #JSONTable
            (
              elementname VARCHAR(500) ,
              elementvalue VARCHAR(500)
            )
        INSERT  INTO #JSONTable
                ( elementname ,
                  elementvalue

                )
                SELECT  NAME ,
                        StringValue
                FROM    dbo.parseJSON(@JSONString)
                WHERE   LEN(StringValue) > 0 AND NAME IS NOT NULL



--declare a csv variable with all the distinct elements
DECLARE @csv NVARCHAR(max) = STUFF(
    (
         SELECT ',' + elementname
         FROM (
              SELECT DISTINCT elementname
              FROM #JSONTable
         ) AS e
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    1,
    1,
    ''
);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT *
    FROM (
       SELECT *, Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY elementname ORDER BY elementname)
       FROM #JSONTable
    ) AS t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(elementvalue)
        FOR elementname IN (' + @csv + ')
    ) AS p
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

But the dictionary values don't correspond to the key.  Here is the results of Umair's current answer:
[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure the parseJSON function works fine.  It gives me a SQL table that has all the keys and values.  The issue comes with the PIVOT section.

Comment: Don't think you quite understood what I was saying. Nothing is wrong with the way your parseJSON function is parsing the json string. BUT information is being lost, particularly to which object a key is associated with. Example: `[{property1:'value1',property2:'value2'},{'property3':'value3'}]` and `[{property1:'value1'},{'property2':'value2',property3:'value3'}]` will produce the same output in your function. So how would you distinguish to which object each key belongs to? Only way to do it is add a new column in the function. Which indicates which object the key belongs to.

Comment: Gotcha.  I will start reviewing that UDF I am using.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
--declare a csv variable with all the distinct elements
DECLARE @csv NVARCHAR(max) = STUFF(
    (
         SELECT ',' + elementname
         FROM (
              SELECT DISTINCT elementname
              FROM #JSONTable
         ) AS e
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    1,
    1,
    ''
);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT *
    FROM (
       SELECT *, Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY elementname ORDER BY elementvalue)
       FROM #JSONTable
    ) AS t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(elementvalue)
        FOR elementname IN (' + @csv + ')
    ) AS p
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

i.e dynamic pivoting :)

Edit:

Since you do not want to aggregate by anything in the pivot, I added a row number function to assign each distinct elementname a sequentially increasing id (based on element value). This will essentially group the pivot by this row column, producing all the required rows.

Comment: The dynamic SQL doesn't know about the @JSONTable variable.  I added to my question the SQL I am using now (including what you suggested).

Comment: Should be able to. Let me give that a shot

Comment: I am getting another error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'.  When that sp_executesql command is run

Comment: BTW this is the SQL that is generated for the sp_executesql - 
     SELECT *
     FROM #JSONTable AS j
     PIVOT (
         MAX(elementvalue)
         FOR elementname IN (ravid,ravversion,taskid)
     )

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I updated my answer to include your latest answer.  We are getting so close.  The values don't match up to the keys right now, any ideas?  Note - I changed the values of that incoming JSON for testing.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm taking a look now!

Comment: Also - I changed your answer a little, went from ORDER BY elementvalue to elementname to see if it would fix the issue, but it didn't.

Comment: Sorry I don't have SSMS on the machine i'm using right now. But I am downloading it! Give me 10mins :)